# Hashicorp Vault reading creds - failed to find entry for connection with name: db_name

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I dont know if I did something wrong or not.

But here is my configuration.

```
// payload.json
{
  "plugin_name": "postgresql-database-plugin",
  "allowed_roles": "*",
  "connection_url": "postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@for-testing-vault.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test-app",
  "username": "test",
  "password": "testtest"
}
```

then run this command:

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." --request POST --data @payload.json http://ip_add.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8200/v1/database/config/postgresql
```

roles configuration:

```
// readonlypayload.json
{
  "db_name": "test-app",
  "creation_statements": ["CREATE ROLE \"{{name}}\" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}';
   GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO \"{{name}}\";"],
  "default_ttl": "1h",
  "max_ttl": "24h"
}
```

then run this command:

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." --request POST --data @readonlypayload.json http://ip_add.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8200/v1/database/roles/readonly
```

Then created a policy:

```
path "database/creds/readonly" {
  capabilities = [ "read" ]
}

path "/sys/leases/renew" {
  capabilities = [ "update" ]
}
```

and run this to get the token:

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." --request POST --data '{"policies": ["db_creds"]}' http://ip_add.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8200/v1/auth/token/create | jq
```

executed this command to get the values:

```
VAULT_TOKEN=... consul-template.exe -template="config.yml.tpl:config.yml" -vault-addr "http://ip_add.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8200" -log-level debug
```

Then I receive this errors:

```
URL: GET http://ip_add.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8200/v1/database/creds/readonly
Code: 500. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
        * failed to find entry for connection with name: "test-app"
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Tried also this command on the server
`vault read database/creds/readonly`

Still returning

```
* 1 error occurred:
        * failed to find entry for connection with name: "test-app"
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Excalibur I wasn't able to find a solution for this, my work around is just use a key value pair.

Answer (score 13):

For those coming to this page via Googling for this error message, this might help:

Unfortunately the Vault database/role's parameter `db_name` is a bit misleading. The value needs to match a `database/config/` entry, not an actual database name per se. The GRANT statement itself is where the database name is relevant, the `db_name` is just a reference to the config name, which may or may not match the database name. (In my case, the configs have other data such as environment prefixing the DB name.)

Comment: This!! So simple, but the documentation assumes that we are calling the config and role the database name, that may not always true. People can create different roles for the same database. It is a little weird that the configs refers the role and the role refers back to the config... but knowing that solved everything

Answer (score 0):

In case this issue not yet resolved

> vault is not able to find the db name 'test-app' in postgres, or authentication to the db 'test-app' with given credential fails, so
>   connection failure happened.

login to postgres and check if the db **'test-app'** exists by running **\l**.

for creating role in postgres you should use the default db **'postgres'**. Try to change name from 'test-app' to 'postgres' and check.

Change connection_url in payload.json:

```
  "connection_url": "postgresql://{{username}}:{{password}}@for-testing-vault.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres",
```

Comment: It's been months now since I last check on this project, but I'm pretty sure I have tried using the default db and work my way around it but to no avail.